# Flux / Flummox: Component stops listening the Store after first router transition

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, flummox

I've just started using `flummox` and I'm a little bit flummoxed :)

Here is my use case.

**App Layout**

```
<section id="layout">
  <Header {...this.props} />
  <RouteHandler {...this.props} />
  <Footer />
  <Alert {...this.props} />
</section>
```

In my App I have `Alert Component`. When something happens I trigger an `AlertAction` from some component, it dispatches alert payload to `AlertStore`, which gets updated, and `AlertComponent` shows alert ( + hides it after some time).

For example I have a `PostEdit Component`. After form submit, I send request to API from `PostActions` and receive response, which is dispatched to `PostStore`. Store gets updated and `PostEdit Component` gets notified. In `PostEdit`'s `componentWillReceiveProps` I check props, received from the store, and trigger `AlertAction` to show the alert.

2 problems:

1. I have to use `setTimeout` to trigger `AlertAction` from the `Post Component` to make alert things happen (code below).
2. And the main problem is that `Alert Component` stops listening `AlertStore` after the first `react-router` transition.

Here is console.log, illustrating the problem:

[image: console.log]

One more strange thing is that changed-store-notification in console.log printed before dispatch-payload-from-action-notification (which causes this store change).

Here are code snippets:

**AlertHandler.jsx**

```
export default class AlertHandler extends React.Component {

  // constructor()

  render() {
    return (
        <FluxComponent connectToStores={'alerts'}>
          <Alert {...this.props} />
        </FluxComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

**Alert.jsx**

```
export default class Alert extends React.Component {

  // constructor()
  // _handleShow()
  // _handleHide()

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.flux.getStore('alerts').addListener('change', function() {
      console.log('Changed!', this.state);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Not gonna happen');
  }

  // render()
}
```

**PostEdit.jsx**

```
export default class PostEdit extends React.Component {

  // constructor()

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false
    }, () => {
      if (newProps.errors) {
        // without `setTimeout` nothing happens
        setTimeout(() => {
          newProps.flux
              .getActions('alerts')
              .showErrorAlert(newProps.errors);
        }, 1);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          newProps.flux
              .getActions('alerts')
              .showSuccessAlert();
        }, 1);
      }
    });
  }

  _submitPost(e) {

    // doing stuff...

    // triggering updatePost action
    this.props.flux
        .getActions('posts')
        .updatePost(post);
  }

  // render()
}
```

Not sure are these bugs or I missed smth in flux/flummox patterns and do things wrong. Thanks for feedback!